# Why is my LI tag not growing with it's child P tag?

Tags: html, css, height

I can't figure out why the li's height is not increasing when the P element does.. I tried all kinds of position and overflow on elements, but just don't see it.. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!

For more code see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sV4Jp/)

HTML:

```
<div class='todo_list'>
        <div class='add_list'>&#43; List</div><br>
        <h3 contenteditable='true'>New List<span class='remove_list' contenteditable='false'></span></h3>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type='checkbox' class='task_status'>
                <p class='task' contenteditable='true'></p>
                <span class='drag'></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class='add_task'>&#43;</div><br>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

div.todo_list{
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ul li{
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ccc;
    border-top: none;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .3s;
    transition: opacity .3s;
}


p,
input[type=checkbox]{
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
}


p{
    top: 0;
    right: 40px;
    left: 38px;
    padding: 12px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is the `position: absolute;` for the `p` and `input` elements.

They go out of the natural page-flow so the `height` of the `li` element won't increase...

Answer (score 1):

You have used:

```
ul li{
    overflow: hidden; // <-- this is the problem I guess
    ...
}
```

Also (Remove the `p` from this) :

```
p, input[type=checkbox] {
    position: absolute; // <-- this is a problem
    height: auto;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sV4Jp/3/):

Comment: Right now your `p` is empty, what happens when you put some data in it ?

Comment: @PepijnGieles You are using `p,
input[type=checkbox]{
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
}` so what do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

```
p,
input[type=checkbox]{
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
}
```

should fix your problem.